# How to only allow entering number between 0-99.99

Tags: c#, validation

How can I restrict the user from entering anything, in a text box, other than a value between 0 to 99.99

My code seems to be working but, it will allow **any number** to be entered. It will allow only number and a dot once. But it will still allow a value greater than 99.99

Below my code:

```
   private void InputMargin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // allow only number and dot
            if (   ! char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && ! char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                && e.KeyChar != '.'
                || (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            )
            {
                //e.Handled = true;
                double margin;
                double.TryParse((sender as TextBox).Text, out margin);

                if (margin >= 0 && margin <= 99.99)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you should use a Masked Text Box?

Comment: why not try a regex something like this `[0-9]{1,2}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{2}`. This may not be the right choice, but can be used as starting point

Answer (score 0):

why not use NumericUpDown control with DecimalPlaces property set to 2.

no need to add any additional coding like on textbox.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using  `&& e.KeyChar != '.' because doing so doesnot accepts '.' .just delete this because you have also used (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1 this accepts only one '.' in the whole textfield so the Right if statement will be.

```
 if (   ! char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && ! char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                || (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            )
    {
//Your Code
}
```